# Possible Memory Leak: new char[strlen()]

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

This is a fairly basic question and I am pretty sure I know the answer, but seeing as the consequence for being wrong is a segfault I figure I should ask. I have been using `strlen()` and the `new char[]` operator in the following way for quite some time now and just noticed something that threw up a red flag:

```
void genericCopy(char *somestring, char *someOtherString) {
    someOtherString = new char[strlen(somestring)];
    strcpy(someOtherString,somestring);
}
```

My question is, seeing as a string should be null terminated, should I be doing this as such:

```
void genericCopy(char *somestring, char *someOtherString) {
    someOtherString = new char[strlen(somestring)+1];
    strcpy(someOtherString,somestring);
    someOtherString[strlen(someOtherString)] = '\0';
}
```

So far I have never had a problem with the first method, but that doesn't mean I'm doing it right. Since the length being return by `strlen()`is the number of characters in the string without the null terminator so new isn't reserving space for '/0'... At least I don't think it is.

Comment: "So far I have never had a problem" .... lucky duck :)

Comment: The 2nd method is better, but neither will sort out the memory leak!

Comment: You don't need to set the terminator yourself: strcpy [does it](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/). Also, you are open to a [TOCTOU attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) by using strcpy instead of strncpy or strlcpy (you should set `n = strlen()` at the top of the function and use that whenever you need the length, rather than call strlen repeatedly).

Comment: @dbaupp I never thought about the TOCTOU problem. Thanks for pointing that out! :-D

Comment: If you're using C++, why not just use `std::string`?

Comment: @dbaupp: It's unlikely that you want to use [`strncpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: @dbaupp: TOCTOU is not an issue unless (a) it's a multi-threaded program, and (b) other threads actually modify the data. And I don't see how using `strncpy()` (bad idea) or `strlcpy()` would address TOCTOU anyway. If other threads are clobbering data, they can as easily do so while `strlcpy()` is executing.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I would assume dbaupp is talking about an actual attack where someone is trying to force your program to do unexpected things... But I'm in no way a security expert so I am going to watch this conversation play out and I will hopefully learn something from it :-)

Comment: @KeithThompson, agree about a, and b (and strncpy). But if another thread came in and changed the null terminator of the source string between the call to `strlen` and the copy, the copy could overrun the destination array. (Since it's heap memory, this might not be easy to use as a security hole, but it could easily crash the program.)

Comment: @dbaupp: If another thread can change the data you're working on, you're pretty much screwed no matter what you do.

Comment: If you use `std::string`, you won't run into problems like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should know that this function of yours is pointless to write, just use [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) (if available on your system).

But yes, you need an additional byte to store the `\0`, so always do something like `new char[strlen(somestring)+1];`. However, there is no need to manually add the `\0`; `strcpy` already does this.

You should use something like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to discover this and similar bugs in your code.

There is however an additional problem in your code; your code will always leak `someOtherString`; it will not be returned to where you called it from. You either need to change your method to something like:

```
char *genericCopy(char *something) {
    char *copy = new char[strlen(somestring)+1];
    strcpy(copy,somestring);
    return copy;
}
```

and then get the copy as follows:

```
copy = genericCopy(something);
```

Or you need to change your method to something like:

```
void genericCopy(char *something, char **copy) {
    *copy = new char[strlen(somestring)+1];
    strcpy(*copy,somestring);
}
```

and call it as:

```
genericCopy(something, &copy);
```

If you'll be using C++ you could also just change the method prototype to:

```
void genericCopy(char* somestring, char*& someOtherString)
```

and call it as:

```
genericCopy(something, copy);
```

Then `someOtherString` will be passed as a reference, and the new value you allocate to it will propagate outside of your method.

Comment: Thanks man! All answers were awesome but yours came first so you get the cookie. Thanks for the referral to Valgrind, it appears to be a powerful tool, I'll look at adding it to my arsenal.

Comment: `strdup()` is non-standard (it's defined by POSIX, but not by the C standard), and a conforming C implementation isn't even allowed to provide a function by that name.

Comment: Then the caller is responsible for applying `delete[]` to the returned pointer; otherwise you still have a memory leak.

Comment: Your second function `char *genericCopy(char *something, char **copy)` fails to return a result. It should be `void genericCopy(char *something, char **copy)`

Comment: On a side note, I am well aware my function is pointless to write as it was a simple example. I could have posted a real function that was several hundred lines long but I value simplicity :-) cheers.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: fixed that prototype. And strdup might be non-standard but I've yet to see a system which doesn't provide it.

Comment: @houbysoft: Visual Studio / Windows doesn't provide `strdup`.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: I always used mingw on Windows, which does provide it. But ok, edited answer to note that it might not be available.

Comment: @houbysoft: `gcc -ansi` or `gcc -std=c99` doesn't recognize `strdup()`; the function is there, but the declaration is hidden.

Comment: Above, I wrote "and a conforming C implementation isn't even allowed to provide a function by that name" (referring to `strdup`). I believe I was mistaken; identifiers starting with `str` are reserved when `<string.h>` is included.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your suspicion is correct. You should be allocating an additional character, and making sure the copied string is null-terminated. (strcpy() itself will do this, but when someone advises to you that you switch to strncpy(), as they no doubt will (it's safer!) you'll need to be extra careful, because it is NOT guaranteed to copy the '/0'.)

If you're already using C++, though, you may be well-advised to switch to using std::string. It's often an easier, less error-prone method of manipulating character arrays.

However, here's the further problem that you need to address. You are assigning your new character array to a COPY of someOtherString. You need to make some changes:

```
void genericCopy(char *somestring, char **someOtherString) {
    *someOtherString = new char[strlen(somestring)+1];
    strcpy(*someOtherString,somestring);
    (*someOtherString)[strlen(somestring)] = '\0';
}
```

This way you will get back the new character buffer outside your function call.